# Prove $f$ is a continuous function if $e^xf(x)$ and $e^{-f(x)}$ are all monotonic decreasing function

Tags: analysis

Q. Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, and suppose $e^xf(x)$ and $e^{-f(x)}$ are all monotonic decreasing function. Prove $f$ is a continuous function.

My try. $e^x$ is increasing function. If $x_1 \lt x_2$, $e^{-f(x_1)} \ge e^{-f(x_2)}$ and $f(x_1) \le f(x_2)$. So $f$ is monotonic increasing function.

And $e^{x_1}f(x_1) \ge e^{x_2}f(x_2)$ i.e. $f(x_1) \ge e^{x_2 - x_1}f(x_2) \gt f(x_2)$. So $f$ is strictly decreasing function.

Now, I got contradiction here. I think I must be confusion something. My hunch is that I did something wrong when I used $e^xf(x)$ and $f$ is actually monotonic decreasing function and constant function. Please help me find what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are implicitly assuming that $f\geq 0$, whereas it must be $f\leq 0$.

Namely, as you have already observed, since $e^{-f}$ is decreasing then also $\log (e^{-f})$ is decreasing, i.e. $f$ is increasing.

On the other hand, if $x_1 < x_2$, you get
$$
e^{x_1} f(x_1) \geq e^{x_2} f(x_2)
\qquad
\text{i.e.}\qquad
f(x_1) \geq e^{x_2-x_1} f(x_2).
$$
Since $f(x_2) \geq f(x_1)$, this implies that $f(x_2)\geq f(x_1) \geq e^{x_2-x_1} f(x_2)$, so that $f(x_2) \leq 0$ for every $x_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

We have now to prove that $f$ (which is increasing and $\leq 0$) is continuous.
Clearly, being a monotone function, it is enough to prove that it has no jump points.

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and denote by $f(x^\pm)$ the right and left limits of $f$ at $x$. Since the function $\varphi(t) := e^t f(t)$ is decreasing, we have that $\varphi(x^+) \leq \varphi(x^-)$, i.e. $f(x^+) \leq f(x^-)$. On the other hand, $f$ is increasing, i.e. $f(x^+) \geq f(x^-)$. 
Hence $f(x^+) = f(x^-)$, i.e. $f$ cannot have a jump at $x$.

Comment: But a function can be discontinuous even if the left and right limits exist and are equal. One example is $f(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 1$.

Comment: But this cannot happen for a monotone function (indeed, I wrote that "it is enough to prove that it has no jump points").

Comment: Now I understand what I've missed. Thank you very much!